# Show that $\left\{\alpha_i \beta_j \mid 1 \leq i \leq k, 1 \leq j \leq m\right\}$ : has $k m$ distincts elements of $K$.

Tags: galois-theory

Let $F \leq E \leq K$ fields. Sea $\left\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots \alpha_k\right\}$ a basis for  the extension $K / E$ y $\left\{\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots \beta_m\right\}$ a basis for  the extension  $E / F$. show that  $\left\{\alpha_i \beta_j \mid 1 \leq i \leq k, 1 \leq j \leq m\right\}$ :
has $k m$ distincts elements of  $K$.

my try:

lets suppose that $\alpha_i\beta_j=\alpha_\ell\beta_n$ for $i \neq \ell$ and $j\neq n$

and then $\alpha_i\beta_j-\alpha_\ell\beta_n=0$ and how $\beta_j, \beta_n \subset E\subset K$ then are linearly independent in $K$
so $\alpha_i=\alpha_j=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: No two elements of $K$ can ever be linearly independent **over $K$**. Please reread the book/lecture notes to learn what kind of linear independence is implied by the phrase "*$\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}$ is a basis for the extension $K/E$*". Ditto for the other.